# Pop up Bootstrap modal on success AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Formkeep to do my forms, using AJAX to submit an email to their servers. What I'm getting stuck on is how do I pop up a bootstrap modal saying 'thanks' on the successful sending of an email address using AJAX.

Here's the script running the AJAX.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#beta-signup').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var formEl = $(this);
        var submitButton = $('input[type=submit]', formEl);

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: formEl.prop('action'),
          accept: {
            javascript: 'application/javascript'
          },
          data: formEl.serialize(),
          beforeSend: function() {
            submitButton.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
          }
        }).done(function(data) {
          submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

I'm a beginner at AJAX requests so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#beta-signup').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var formEl = $(this);
        var submitButton = $('input[type=submit]', formEl);

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: formEl.prop('action'),
          accept: {
            javascript: 'application/javascript'
          },
          data: formEl.serialize(),
          beforeSend: function() {
            submitButton.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
              }
        success: function(data) {
           $('#your-modal').modal('toggle');
          }
        }).done(function(data) {
          submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

After your done call back, add:

```
 success: function(data) {
               $('#your-modal').modal('toggle');
              }
```

And make sure your modal has similar attributes as:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="your-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note* depending on your page set up, you'll probably want to add the style="hidden" to you modal.

Comment: Hi @Mark I'm currently getting an 'Unexpected identifier' on the line with this "success: function(data) {"

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some elements.

HTML (Simple markup for the modal):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmation</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Success message</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS (Add this code to your success return):

```
// Your code
}).done(function(data) {
    submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
    $('#myModal').modal({'show' : true});
});
```