# Bootstrap Modal popup not showing up first time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

While I first click this `#btnRequestedProviderSelect` button, bootstrap modal is not showing popup. But I second click it will come why?

```js
$("#btnRequestedProviderSelect").click(function () {
  $("#hdnORProvider").val('Requested');
  $.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    async: false,
    url: settings.ProviderSearchPopupURL,
    data: {
      coverageID: 0,
      fromPage: settings.Frompage, HPID: $('#MemberHealthPlanID').val(),
      LOBID: $("#MemberLOBID").val(), IPAID: $("#MemberIPAID").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#divProviderSearch").html(data);
      $("#divProviderSearchPopup").modal();
      $('#divProviderSearchPopup').modal({
        keyboard: false
      });
      $('#divProviderSearchPopup').modal('show');
    }
  });    
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you get errors in browser console? Also try to remove `async: false` and provide contents of `data` in success result.

Comment: if i remove async:false means it will go to some other ajax without complete this...and data is also fine

Comment: Anyone faced issue like this ???

Comment: Is this already tried: `$('#divProviderSearchPopup').modal('toggle');`? Also consider to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672304/bootstrap-mymodal-modalshow-is-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482680/pop-up-bootstrap-modal-on-success-ajax-call), ensure that you're not loaded same script twice.

Comment: u told that $('#divProviderSearchPopup').modal('show'); for this i have to use $('#divProviderSearchPopup').modal('toggle') ryt??

Comment: I'm not getting any issue like this Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function......and even if i will try this also how can i use {keyboard: false} on modal 
 $('#divProviderSearchPopup').modal('toggle');

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue